# What is the impact if delay kafka manual commit offset

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We want to manual commit kafka offset to control data lose events. But we might delay the manaul commit as we want to do this only after persisting to datasource

I would like to learn how slowing down a commit offset impact kafka's topic/paralalism/partition if at all

Comment: What do you mean by `kafka's topic/paralalism/partition` ?

Comment: @RanLupovich we are implementing at least once (because we have a dedup mechanism in place). I was saying that from the sec I poll the message and until I manually commit will this "buffer" time might impact somehow on the other consumers? e.g they wont be able to consume message until I commit etc..

Comment: @nipuna I was asking what would be the impact of delaying manual commit on the kafka cluster. Will it in anyway delay other consumers (of the same topic) to keep polling new messages from the same topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you consume from one topic, if that consumers belongs to one consumer group, Kafka will make sure one partition consumed by one consumer. So if you commit manually it will not affect to other consumers because they consuming from another partition.

But if you compare same partition consumer with `enable.auto.commit=false` and `enable.auto.commit=true`, that auto commit enabled consumers throughput if relatively high. And if you don't need the confirmation of your commits, then use commitAsync, it will improve throughput than commitSync.

> Generally, you call the API when you are finished processing all the messages in a batch, and don’t poll for new messages until the last offset in the batch is committed. This approach can can affect throughput and latency, as can the number of messages returned when polling, so you can set up your application to commit less frequently.

But, if you do manual committing, There can be duplicate consumed messages when consumer restarts or rebalances. When you consume a message and write to your db, after that you are going to commit the message to Kafka. If consumer rebalance or restart at that time, that message will not be committed and will be re-consumed by another consumer in same group.

For more informations, please refer

- [consumer-tuning](https://strimzi.io/blog/2021/01/07/consumer-tuning/)
- [how-to-commit-offsets](https://riptutorial.com/apache-kafka/example/19389/how-to-commit-offsets)

Comment: thanks for your response. you wrote " So if you commit manually it will not affect to other consumers because they consuming from another partition" But what happens if I consume from different consumer-groups and one of the consumers is delaying the manual commit? what could be the impact?

Comment: It will not impact to other consumers. because it is a different process, i mean different group and different consumer session for the Kafka. There is no dependancy on that.

Comment: so following what you saying if a manual commit is being delayed from the moment it was polled until the actual commit event no impact will occour anyhow